# EventEmitter - Could not listen an Event

Tags: node.js, express, eventemitter

Everyone.

I'm trying to apply observer pattern in my app.
But, the problem is subscribers can not listen event.
When a function(useEvent.js) fired event, nothing happened.
Written below is my codes.

payment.js

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')


class PaymentEvent extends EventEmitter {
    getPaid(paymentId) {
        this.emit('create', paymentId)
        console.log('Created')
    }
}


module.exports = PaymentEvent
```

subscriber.js

```
const PaymentEvent = require('./payment')
const payment = new PaymentEvent()
payment.on('create', paymentId => {
    console.log('Event Fired!!!')})

// Expected : 'Event Fired!!!'
// Result : Nothing happened
...
```

useEvent.js

```
const PaymentEvent = require('./payment')

const createPayment = async data => {
    const payment = await CorePayment.create(data)
    const paymentId = payment.id
    const paymentEvent = new PaymentEvent()
    
    // This parts of code will fire event! 
    paymentEvent.getPaid(paymentId)
    return paymentId
}
...
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The `payment` to which `subscriber.js` listens is different from the `paymentEvent` that emits the event. So raising an event on the one does not cause the other to react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comment, you're creating multiple instances of `PaymentEvent`, which means you create multiple, *different*, event emitters.

Instead, you can instantiate `PaymentEvent` in `payment.js` and import the resulting instance when you need it:

```
// payment.js
…
module.exports = new PaymentEvent;

// subscriber.js
const paymentEvent = require('./payment');
paymentEvent.on(…)

// useEvent.js
const paymentEvent = require('./payment');
…
paymentEvent.getPaid(paymentId);
…
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to follow as your guide... But, unfortunately, it could not fixed. Maybe there are another issue, I guess...

Comment: @Maker I assume that you're running all code inside the same Node.js process? (and also that all files, especially the subscriber, are actually being loaded)

Comment: As you said... subscribers are not loaded. I don't have any idea to load it. But I'm digging in...

Comment: @Maker might be as simple as just `require()`ing the file